# Is there an equivalent firmware I can use for the TSSTcorp TS-L633C AC01 DVD writer/player?

Tags: dvd, firmware

I can't seem to locate any firmware information for the TSSTcorp TS-L633C AC01 DVD writer/player and was wondering if there was another version's firmware I could use.

Comment: "was wondering if there was another version's firmware I could use" - For *what*? What doesn't the current firmware allow you to do?

Comment: @Karan - I would like to downgrade or possibly upgrade the firmware as I seem to be having issues with the DVD player/writer

Comment: Are you sure it's not a hardware issue (that a firmware update won't fix)? I found Korean versions [SC00](http://tinyurl.com/btqheq2), [SC01](http://tinyurl.com/bqsnef8) and [KC00](http://tinyurl.com/c4be3e3). There seem to be [many other regional variants](http://burners.burn4free.com/toshiba-samsung-storage-technology-corporation/tsstcorp-ts-l633c.htm) available, but you'll need to search for them and might very well end up bricking your drive if you don't install a version meant for the **AC** region (for which AC01 seems to be the latest).

Comment: What part of the world is AC01? Central America? Then what part of the world is KC00? Central Korea? And what about SC01 then? These are not exactly what I would call regions, but rather cryptic codes for what may or may not be geographical regions. But it would seem to me that the "C" is insignificant. Where did you get the string "TSSTcorp TS-L633C AC01" from?

Answer (score 0):

## What and Where

Given the following codes it would seem to me as if the "C" letter is insignificant.

```
AC01
AC02
KC00
SC01
```

I don't know this for a fact, but if the second letter is insignificant, then you may find "A07" and "A08" firmware for "TSST TS-L633C" on Softpedia at the following URL.

https://drivers.softpedia.com/downloadTag/TSST%20TS-L633C%20Firmware

The higher the number, the newer the version. So for example A08 is newer than A07. Similarly, AC02 would be newer than AC01. Assuming one is made available, you could use AC02 to upgrade your firmware from AC01. Although, I suspect that the "AC02" firmware was only released as stock firmware on "TS-L633C" models that rolled out of the factory, not as a binary download you could get over the Internet. I have come to this conclusion after some extensive google-fu and viewing some dodgy websites that claim otherwise.

Another resource for downloading firmware files is Firmeware HQ.

https://www.firmwarehq.com/Samsung/TS-L633C/files.html

You will find the following files here.

```
Version Date desc           Filename
SC01    22nd April, 2010    TS-L633C_SC01.exe
DW50    5th April, 2010     R260056.exe
SC00    26th February, 2010 TS-L633C_SC00.exe
TG00    7th January, 2010   TS-L633C_TG00.exe
AS01    25th August, 2009   TSST_TS-L633C_AS01.zip
KC00    18th May, 2009      TS-L633C_KC00.exe
```

If the letters don't carry any particular meaning, then you may just sort the versions in alphabetical order to discern which one is the latest. If we do that we get the following list, from oldest to newest.

```
AC01
AC02
AS01
DW50
KC00
SC00
SC01
TG00
```

I don't know if this is correct. I have not found any documentation or even mentions online that would indicate what these letters mean, everyone seems to just assume that these letters stand for region in which the drives were sold.

I am speculating when I say this, but as long as the model is the same, I think the only adverse effect of using the firmware from the "wrong region" would be that you can't play for example a Region 1 DVD video disc (USA, Canada) in a TS-L633C unit that's sold for the Region 2 market (Japan, Europe, South Africa, Middle East, Greenland). But this is not so much relevant anymore because Windows 10 cannot play DVD video discs anyway, not without paying an extra premium or getting a third party solution.

**Update:** Upon closer inspection I see that A07 and A08 appear to be DELL internal version numbers for their various laptop models. The A07 contains "L633CDW50.bin" (firmware DW50) and A08 contains "L633CDW60.bin" (firmware DW60). Both of these can be downloaded directly from DELL using the links below. The date stamps below are taken from the "Version.txt" files are most likely to be dates when the DELL update packages were created, and not necessarily when the firmware files were created. I have also included some info on what issues these upgrades are intended to fix. Also note that these DELL packages contain the TSDNWIN tool needed for doing the upgrade (1.00.c), in addition to the "TSDNDOS.EXE" tool for DOS.

**A07**

> Fixes: Fixes auto-run issue when media is inserted.

You can get it here:
http://ftp.us.dell.com/rmsd/R260056.exe

```
Version    : A07
OEM Name   : TSST
OEM Ver    : DW50
Created    : Mon Apr 5 01:31:16 CDT 2010
```

**A08**

> Fixes: Improved CDDA playback on some discs.

You can get it here:
https://downloads.dell.com/rmsd/R304507.exe

Or here:
http://ftp.us.dell.com/rmsd/R304507.exe

```
Version    : A08
OEM Name   : TSST
OEM Ver    : DW60
Created    : Wed May 18 01:18:15 CDT 2011
```

## How to Upgrade

The previously deleted answer was pointing to this URL.

http://aps2.toshiba-tro.de/kb0/TSB9C02RP0000R01ES.htm

The site has been taken offline since, but an archived version can be found at the following URL.

https://web.archive.org/web/20180119225444/http://aps2.toshiba-tro.de/kb0/TSB9C02RP0000R01ES.htm

It's an original Toshiba help article ("TSST" is Toshiba and Samsung) on how to upgrade the firmware of "TS-L633C" from TO01 to TO02, and from TF01 to TF02. It also shows you how to identify the drive model and firmware version you have using Device Manager as well as flashing the firmware using TSDNWIN.

### Identify drive model and firmware version

1. Open Device Manager.
2. Expand the DVD/CD-ROM drives category.
3. Double click on your model name.
4. Go to Details tab.
5. Select "Hardware Ids" from the Property list.

[image: identify firmware version]

The very first line in of "Hardware Ids" should indicate what firmware version you have. In my example above, it's "SB00" for my "SH-224DB" drive.

### Upgrading using TSDNWIN

This is the official tool from TSST that would have been used for upgrading the firmware. You can still download this tool from Softpedia from the following URL.

https://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Miscellaneous/TSDNWIN.shtml

Here I am running it on Windows 10 (build 19042.870).

[image: tsdnwin about window]

[image: tsdnwin main window]

Note that the automatic firmware download button no longer works. That's because TSST has been out of business since around 2016 and the servers have gone offline. But if you have the firmware image file you can use this tool to upgrade the drive. This is what the Toshiba help article would have you use.

## Disclaimer

**I take no responsibility if these methods don't work or if you end up bricking your drive.**